# Can we reduce camera flash light brightness in android?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, flashlight

I want to change the camera flash light brightness in my android application...
Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Android system does not provide you with this behavior.

I believe that the only way that you can manage to change the flash level brightness at this point is with a manufacturer's custom SDK.  Certain manufacturers open up the capability to do other features that the Google Android system does not do out of the box. This is when you will typically hear someone mentioning that "it will work for some devices".

For instance, you can include the Samsung mobile SDK in your build, and use their features when you detect a Samsung device.  In this way you can take advantage of certain features they have enabled when your app is running on a Samsung device.  Their camera API features can be referenced here: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera

At first glance I do not see any API that they introduced in order to change the brightness of the flash for Samsung devices which is unfortunate, but other manufacturers out there might provide you with the means to do so in a similar manner.

I would have thought at this time, Android would have this capability and I am unsure why they haven't added it into the operating system at this point to give us finer control over that flash.