# Change Android flashlight brightness

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I'm looking for something like this:

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
cameraManager.setTorchMode("0", true);
cameraManager.setTorchLevel("0", 2); //change the brightness based on the number given
```

Comment: There are quite a few duplicates of this question, did none of them help?

Comment: there was one recent discussion about this but it was not helpful at all

Comment: These seem to suggest that there isn't a way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357241/flashled-intensity-controls | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285498/can-we-reduce-camera-flash-light-brightness-in-android | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167430/controlling-the-brightness-of-the-flashlight-in-android | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701937/is-the-flashlight-intensity-brightness-controllable-on-android

Comment: but these are all old topics. I believe ability to adjust flashlight brightness was added after android oreo or pie.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: I'm not really sure about other android manufactures except Samsung. https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/theres-easy-way-change-flashlight-brightness-your-galaxy-phone-0214247/

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to adjust the brightness of the flashlight ?

Answer (score 1):

This will work only on devices with android 13 and new version of camera hardware abstraction layer (tested on pixel 6 pro). It might also work on some samsung devices with lower android version (not tested).

Answer (score 1):

Try this CameraManager API:

`public void Turnontorch() throws CameraAccessException { if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) { camManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraId,TorchStrength); }`

The range of TorchStrength can be from **1 to CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL.**

For more details, refer
[Control the Strength of Torch(only for Android 13 or higher)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(java.lang.String,%20int))